# how to delete file in input directory and output directory

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

In Apache camel,if i delete a file in input directory meanwhile the same file should also be deleted in output directory automatically? am new to Apache camel please suggest me some ideas.

thank you,

Answer (score 1):

That is not how the Camel file component is designed. Its not a file sync tool. You can use rsync or some other tool for that.

The Camel file component is for picking up new files in a directory. It only reacts on new files, not on files being deleted.

Comment: for example if i had 6 files in from endpoint and i moved 6 files to to endpoint,i delete one file in from endpoint the same file also deleted in to endpoint.is there any other way to do this in camel..?

Comment: No as I already said. You can write your own code to delete the file or use some tool that is intended for syncing files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not read the camel documentation because as Claus Ibsen states, Cmael is not a file sync tool. You should find another tool if you have deletition to be a trigger mechanism.